# Filter NSNumber Objects in NSMutableArray Without NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I feel like I have a unique problem.  This problem stems from parsing a COLLADA XML file.  I am filtering by whitespace in the  element of the file, and it's working fine, except when I dump that to an NSArray, I get a bunch of junk zero values before I hit the actual points I am trying to isolate.

My question is… If my NSMutableArray has a bunch of NSNumber values, and I want to filter out all zero values, how can I do this?

I thought I could do something like:

```
NSNumber * newNumber;
NSMutableArray * newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(oldNumber in oldMutableArray)
{
    if(oldNumber != 0)
    {
        [newArray addObject: oldNumber];
    }
}
```

This does not work, however. :)

Comment: `The problem is, that is not working...` That's not a problem, that's a conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue here is that `!= 0` is really checking for nil values, not if the NSNumber is equal to 0.

You should be able to just do this:

```
[allXMLObjects removeObject:@(0)];
```

This will remove all occurrences of NSNumbers that have a numerical value of 0.

Answer (score 0):

Add `oldNumber`, not `newNumber`. `newNumber` was `nil`

```
NSMutableArray * newarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(oldNumber in oldmutablearray)
{
    if(oldnumbervalues != 0)
    {
        [newarray addObject: oldNumber];  //Add old number, not newNumber. newNumber was nil
    }
}
```